# React with fetch api data show in console but don't retrieve

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

With Fetch API and useState, I try to fetch data from TMDB. After writing some code data is shown in the console correctly but can't retrieve.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import MovieCard from '../components/MovieCard'
import { TrendingMovie } from '../components/Config'

export default function Trending() {
   const [trendingList, setTrendingList] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
         let res = await fetch(TrendingMovie(1))
         let data = await res.json()
         setTrendingList(data.results)
      }

      fetchData()

   }, [])

console.log(trendingList)

return (
  <div>
    {trendingList && trendingList[0]?.adult}
</div>
)}
```

[image]

Comment: You never use your variable

Comment: You are storing data in `trendingList` but using `TrendingMovie` to render the DOM

Answer (score 2):

Well, `adult` has the value of `false` and [booleans do not render by default in React](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-show-boolean-value).

You can render boolean values by first converting them to strings: `String(trendingList[0]?.adult)`.

So instead you could do:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {trendingList && String(trendingList[0]?.adult)}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
{TrendingMovie && TrendingMovie[0]?.adult}
```

You are tellig your code to render TrendingMovie[0]?.adult if your state value is true.

Try:

```
{TrendingMovie[0]?.adult && TrendingMovie}
```

Comment: Still don't work

Comment: @sami you need to check if your property is returning an undefined value to trigger the && operand by doing {TrendingMovie[0]?.adult == undefined && TrendingMovie}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are rendering it wrong. You are console logging `trendingList` and rendering component `TredingMovie`

Try this

```
return <div>{trendingList && trendingList[0]?.adult}</div>;
```

Comment: Still don't work

Answer (score 0):

After using this code app work correctly

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
        let res = await fetch(TrendingMovie(1))
        let data = res.json().then(({ results }) => setTrendingList(results))
       } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
  }
  
}
```